# C# convenient Exception handling for the lazy

Tags: c#, exception

Is there any possible way to automatically append all strings/etc to a textbox(or other form) of my choice? Right now in-order to do that in any class outside of the Main class, I have to route it into it and then use the Main class to post it.

**Clarification(CHANGED):** 
I am no longer looking to just handle exceptions. I really just want to pass a string/text from anywhere in my program without having to pass it to the MainWindow.

```
namespace MyProgram 
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Main goes here...
    }

}

namespace People 
{
    public class Worker
    {
        public void printToLog()
        {
            textBoxErrorlog.AppendText("Message....");
        }
    } 
}
```

The code above won't work. I would have to return the string to the MainWindow class and append it from there (bc textBoxErrorlog doesn't exist in Worker). I would like to skip that step and just post it from the Worker class.

Comment: What do you mean "all exceptions"? Do you mean all unhandled exceptions? The simplest is to not catch them, then your app will crash and you'll have to fix your bug.

Comment: Add code!  Show us what you're doing.  Saying "route it into it" doesn't paint a clear picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague. But I have a feeling you'll find these events interesting/useful:

```
Application.ThreadException
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
```

EDIT after your added code:

Generally speaking it's bad to catch `Exception`. In your case I would recommend hooking into `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and in that handler append to the MainWindow's exception log textbox.

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.IsTerminating)
        {
            MainWindow mw = GetRefToTheMainWindowSomehow();
            mw.AppendException(e.ExceptionObject);
        }
    }
```

And in MainWindow:

```
    internal delegate void AppendExceptionDelegate(Exception e);

    public void AppendException(Exception e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new AppendExceptionDelegate(AppendException), new[] { e });
        }
        else
        {
            this._textBox.Text += e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated my problem. I'm looking for a simpler way to do things. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I dunno if you can get much simpler than this. The AppendException method is complicated because of the way the GUI thread and controls work in WinForms.

Comment: What about WPF/XAML? I'm not using WinForms. There's no way to just pass a string instead of all that exception stuff? From your code above, it appears that I can only use it with exceptions.

Comment: I've changed my example to reflect more what I would like.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom appender for [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) and have it do it.  Other than that you need to catch the exceptions and marshall them back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage wiring up the [`UnhandledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event from the [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w124b5fa.aspx) and routing all unhandled exceptions to whatever you like.

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) => { /* Write To Wherever */ };
```

I would recommend fleshing that out to using a real handler etc, but it gives you an idea.